# Align Imageview in LinearLayout by code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, alignment, imageview

the question is simple, i am creating a imageview dynamically using code.

```
ImageView btnSend = new ImageView (this);
```

and add it to a LinearLayout, the problem is that I want to leave right-aligned

how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using LayoutParams:

```
LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.root_layout);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;

ImageView btnSend = new ImageView (this); 
btnSend.setLayoutParams(params);
rootLayout.addView(btnSend);
```

The only problem is that I don't remember if `params.gravity` sets the content gravity or layout_gravity. Layout_gravity is what you're wanting to change in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call setGravity() on LinearLayout:

```
yourLinLay.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

or in XML:

```
<LinearLayout android:gravity="right">
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setGravity%28int%29
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html