# ImageView - how to inflate or add programmatically?

Tags: android, imageview

I am programmatically adding ImageView without success. Is there any simple way to add ImageView into Activity programmatically?

Thx

Edit:

I have tried this and it is not working.

```
                for(Bitmap b: photoField){
                try{
                    Log.d("BIT", "Bitmapa "+b);
                    if(b!=null){
                        ImageView imv=new ImageView(PoiDisplay.this);
                        imv.setImageBitmap(b);
                    }
                }catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Using a LinearLayout.
Check [this][1] answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616445/align-imageview-in-linearlayout-by-code

Comment: Now you have to add this imageview in your layout. Do get your activity root view and just add these imageviews in it. using addView() method.

Comment: Suppose, your layout's main rootview is LinearLayout then get it using findViewById() and than in this for loop just add these imageviews in that LinearLayout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get the layout id in which u want to place the images
then

```
Relative or Linear or any other layout..

RelativeLayout urLayoutId=(RelativeLayout)finViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutIdInXml);

    for(Bitmap bitmap: photoField){
                    try{

                        if(bitmap!=null){
                            ImageView img=new ImageView(PoiDisplay.this);
                            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            urLayoutId.addView(img);
                        }
                    }catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know too, how to add into View "empty row"? I am adding images dynamicaly a this makes them lying one on each other. Is there any way how to solve this?

Comment: @Waypoint - Use LInearLayout instead of RelativeLayout and give orientation: vetical.

Comment: @user370305 - this is good, but I need to use relative layout. I am adding images one by another, but it seems they have fixed spacing. Is it possible to change it somehow? ImageView.setPadding doesn't work

Comment: try this    urLayoutId.addView(new ImageView(this).setImageBitmap(b));

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
ImageView i=new ImageView(this);
i.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are only creating it not adding it. To add your view on layout. First create or fetch layout.

LinearLayout lp = (LinearLayout) findViewByid(R.id.linear_layout_name)

```
            for(Bitmap b: photoField){
            try{
                Log.d("BIT", "Bitmapa "+b);
                if(b!=null){
                    ImageView imv=new ImageView(PoiDisplay.this);
                    imv.setImageBitmap(b);
                    lp.addview(imv)
                }
            }catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```